# If message contains a server invite link

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to make an auto-moderation system, so the Bot will warn members who sent a server invite link. How can I do so?
Example code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.isInvite():
        print("warn")
```

Comment: If my answer helped you, could you accept it? Else could you describe how it didn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i've seen, discord server links start with `discord.gg`.
So you could use:

```
if 'discord.gg' in message:
    print('warn')
```